# swift PUT API Call missing parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I Keep getting an **Error Code 400: Missing parameters**
I believe the problem is the format i am sending the data in

API DOC: http://middleware.idxbroker.com/docs/api/methods/index.html#api-Leads-putLead

I believe the required data the call needs is the First Name, Last Name, and email, do I need to send the other field as nil or can i leave them blank?

API Call

```
/// Send Lead to IDX Broker
///
/// - Parameter lead: new Lead data fields
/// - Returns: configs for URL Session
class func putLead(lead: String) -> URLRequest {

    let urlString = "https://api.idxbroker.com/leads/lead"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    var downloadTask = URLRequest(url: (url as URL?)!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 20)
    /******************** Add Headers required for API CALL *************************************/
    downloadTask.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    downloadTask.setValue(APICalls.getAccessKey(), forHTTPHeaderField: "accesskey")
    downloadTask.setValue("json", forHTTPHeaderField: "outputtype")
    downloadTask.httpMethod = "PUT"
    downloadTask.httpBody = lead.data(using: .utf8)
    /******************** End Headers required for API CALL *************************************/

    return downloadTask
}
```

Data Sent to Function

```
 /// Create lead from text fields
    let postString = "lead(firstName=\(String(describing: firstName.text!))&lastName=\(String(describing: lastName.text!))&=email=\(String(describing: Email.text!)))"

    /// URL Encoding for put API
    let escapedString = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
    print(escapedString!)
    print(escapedString?.data(using: .utf8) ?? "Error")

    /// API Call with passing json String
    let downloadTask = APICalls.putLead(lead: escapedString!)


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadTask, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        /// Status Returned from API CALL
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }


    }).resume()
    /******** End URL Session **********/
```

Comment: The `postString` should be something like this: `let postString = "firstName=\(firstName.text!)&lastName=\(lastName.text!)&email=\(Email.text!)"`, reading the API DOC.

Comment: I tried that still get a [Status Code: 400 - Required parameter missing or invalid.]

Comment: Anyway, something like `lead(...)` is not a valid format for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You may be missing some other header fields, or any of the three fields `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` may contain invalid data. Nothing more can be said, just reading the API DOC. (You should use `.urlQueryAllowed` instead of `.urlHostAllowed`, but it does not cause problems if the three fields have valid data.)

Answer (score 0):

400 means the API is not getting on or more of the parameters you are passing. If the API received firstName then it would respond with an error stating that lastName was not received. If fist and last are passed then it would respond with email not received.

Testing your code I was able to get the expected string when I didn't use lead() in postString.